# Easy Markdown to Latex to PDF Workflow?

Tags: software-recommendation, latex, markdown

My SO has to produce reports in the same format every week, but getting her to use styles in a word processor with a custom template hasn't worked out, so I'm going anther way.

I'd like to use Markdown with her that converts to LaTeX with custom functions and produces a PDF for printing, all with as little work from her as possible outside of saving the file.

Niceties:

- Immediate preview of Markdown in a side pane
- Formatting buttons
- Online / GDrive / Dropbox integration for the editor
- Sync of printed output to her Dropbox

Suggested method to piece this together?

Comment: Use pandoc. It will take a markdown file and spit out a PDF. Doesn't have any of the niceties. On the other hand, very customizable.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at it. Will it use a defined LaTeX template?

Comment: See example 14 in http://pandoc.org/demos.html

Comment: Also see https://stackedit.io/editor

Comment: Thanks a ton. I'll look into scripting something using that as part of the process, I guess.